# Nullify a 2D matrix with some set of operations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, matrix, mathematical-optimization

```
Given an N x M matrix having only positive integer values, we have to nullify the matrix 
i.e make all entries 0.
We are given two operations
1) multiply each element of any one column at a time by 2.
2) Subtract 1 from all elements of any one row at a time

Find the minimum number of operations required to nullify the matrix.
```

i thought of doing something related to LCM but could not reach to a solution

Comment: Quite an interesting set of operations this of yours; I was expecting some additional column-by-row multiplications. Good luck, bro'! (:

Comment: How familiar are you with the concept of the algebric constructs group and field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first solve for 1 row first and we can extend it to all rows. Let's take a random example:

```
6 11 5 13
```

The goal is to make all elements as 1. First we make 5 (smallest element) as 1. For this we need to subtract 4 (i.e subtract 1 four times). The resultant array is:

```
2 7 1 9
```

Now we multiply 1 with 2 and subtract all row elements by 1:

```
1 6 1 8
```

Next, we multiply 2 1's by 2 and subtract all row elements by 1:

```
1 5 1 7
```

Continuing in this manner, we get to `1 1 1 1`. Now we subtract 1 to get `0 0 0 0`.

Next, we get to other rows and do the same like above. The row we nullified above are all zeroes so multiplication by 2 when manipulating other rows doesn't change the already nullified rows.

The question of finding the minimum number of operations would also depend on the row sequence we select. I think that would be to select a row whose maximum is minimum (among other rows) first. I need to verify this.

Comment: This is a nice idea but not an answer, it's a method to nullify the matrix but you have not shown it is in the minimum number of operations.

Comment: I left that as an exercise to the user :).

Answer (score 0):

How about using Breadth-First Search? Wouldn't that give the shortest path from the original matrix to the nullified matrix? Just build an implicit graph, where each edge corresponds to a single operation on the matrix. Sure, the graph can be huge, but BFS guarantees that the algorithm terminates as soon as the nullified matrix is reached. And it will be in the minimum number of steps/operations.